# ClassCastException when upgrading from Java6 to Java7 due to missing GenericArrayType

Tags: java, generics, java-7

My code runs in Java 5 and 6, but when I upgraded to Java 7 I get a "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.GenericArrayType".

For the following code:

```
public class A<T> {
  public Vector<Integer[]> arr;
}

System.out.println(((ParameterizedType)A.class.getField("arr").getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) A.class.getField("arr").getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass());
```

Java6 prints:

```
java.lang.Integer[]
class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl
```

Java7 prints:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
class java.lang.Class
```

This different behavior is breaking my code which relies on generics. Can someone please help me understand why this happens and how to get [GenericArrayType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericArrayType.html) from `Vector<Integer[]> arr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for `GenericArrayType` states it represents an *array type whose component type is either a parameterized type or a type variable*.

In the given example the array type is `Integer[]`. The component type, `Integer`, is neither a parameterized type nor a type variable. So your array type really should never have been represented by a `GenericArrayType`.

So apparently JRE6 behavior was buggy and it got fixed. Sorry. :(

Comment: The Java bug http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7151486 describes a similar situation.  I'm hitting this change in behaviour between Java 6 and Java 7.  It can be coded around, but is a pain.